# Kafka: exactly once semantics configuration using Apache Beam

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to configure exactly once semantics in Kafka (Apache Beam).
Here are the changes what I'm going to introduce:

**Producer:**

1. `enable.idenpotence` = true
2. `transactional.id` = uniqueTransactionalId

**Consumer:**

1. set `enable.auto.commit` = false

   // added the following to consumer builder:
2. `.commitOffsetsInFinalize()`
3. `.withReadCommitted()`

Added the following to **`KafkaIO#write`** builder:

1. `.withEOS(numShards, sinkGroupId)`

Does anyone know what else should be changed to achieve exactly once semantics in Apache Beam KafkaIO?

Does the configuration above looks fine or I misunderstood smth?

Do I need to specify the `transactional.id` property if I do not use transaction API (because I do not have explicit producer in apache beam)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, looks like I finally found out the proper settings that fit my requirements. Here is what I ended up with:

1) `KafkaIO.Read`:

- update consumer properties with `enable.auto.commit = false`
- `.withReadCommitted()`
- `.commitOffsetsInFinalize()`

2) `KafkaIO#write`:

- `.withEOS(numShards, sinkGroupId)`

  It will also enable idempotence and set the `transactional.id` under the hood for the producer.

So as the result, with such settings we will have **at-least-once** semantics on read, and **exactly-once** semantics 
on write.

Comment: were you able to get this to work on a flink runner?

Comment: @Yomal I haven't tried with flink